# Displaying window with sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

I looked for some tutorials for game development, I found one where I'm supposed to create a pong clone, but I can't even create the window, I get the following:

"Unhandled exception at 0xEEFFEE01 in Pang.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xEEFFEE01."

I'm using SFML 1.6 and Visual Studio 2013.

Here is my code.

**Game.cpp**

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Game.h"

  void Game::Start(void)
  {
if (_gameState != Uninitialized)
    return;

_mainWindow.Create(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768, 32), "Pang!");
_gameState = Game::Playing;

while (!IsExiting())
{
    GameLoop();
}

_mainWindow.Close();
}

bool Game::IsExiting()
{
if (_gameState == Game::Exiting)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

void Game::GameLoop()
{
    sf::Event currentEvent;
while (_mainWindow.GetEvent(currentEvent))
{

    switch (_gameState)
    {
    case Game::Playing:
    {
                          _mainWindow.Clear(sf::Color(255, 0, 0));
                          _mainWindow.Display();

                          if (currentEvent.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                          {
                              _gameState = Game::Exiting;
                          }
                          break;
    }
    }
}
}


Game::GameState Game::_gameState = Uninitialized;
sf::RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow;
```

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "SFML/Window.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

class Game
{

public:
static void Start();

private:
static bool IsExiting();
static void GameLoop();

enum GameState {
    Uninitialized, ShowingSplash, Paused,
    ShowingMenu, Playing, Exiting
};

static GameState _gameState;
static sf::RenderWindow _mainWindow;
};
```

**Pang.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Game::Start();
return 0;
}
```

I know there's some code that has nothing to do with my problem, the error occurs when it reaches this line in Game.cpp

```
_mainWindow.Display();
```

I'm new on this so any help, any good tutorials or starting point to start learning will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Some general SFML advice: Update to SFML 2.0, especially if you are using VS2013. Here are the official SFML tutorials http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/

It looks like you just copied your code from here http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10855.0 if this is true you should have realized that the code did not work, if not then the person who copied the code and used it in their tutorial should have noticed, and the fact they didn't is worrying about the state of the rest of their tutorials

Okay so the issue is you can't have a static RenderWindow, and with that your entire game class should not be static, it just isn't good programming practice. What you need to do is remove the static identifier from every declaration in your Game.h header file. For instance:

This

```
static void Start();
```

Needs to look like this

```
void Start();
```

Next, your Pang.cpp should look like this

```
//#include "stdafx.h" you don't need this precompiled header
#include "Game.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Game myGame;
    myGame.Start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I DID actually copy the code from a tutorial but not that page, I even tried to make the window from scratch by myself but I couldn't and I got some errors.

Thanks for the advice, I'll try it later.